# VideoJs with iOS 14

Tags: javascript, ios, angular

We have a Webapp project with angular 9, and we used of VideoJS 4.1.0 for record video. It work on win 10 and android and etc, and latest version of browsers... , also it worked on iOS 13.7. now, it dose not work on iOS 14. it can not load on any browsers (safari, chrome, Firefox,...) on iOS14.

1. how do I fix It?
2. have any other package for use instead VideoJS?